# How can i update the cache of a WebView every day?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I have a WebView which caches a Website. If the user hasn't a Internet Connection the site in the cache loads. How can i update the cache only 1 time per day.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default
    if ( !CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(getActivity()) ) { // loading offline
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }

    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: I see `WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT` and `WebSettings.*LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK*`

Comment: If the website sets the request headers correctly, webview should respect the headers and cache the website for the duration that is set by the website.

Comment: @hoomi who can i do this?

Comment: take a look here http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

Comment: @hoomi what should i do in my case?

Comment: If you read it to the end, it explains what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Implement gcm in your app, then message your client when you want to update the WebView's cache.